# Mehrune's Razor effect in 4e (aka Original Vorpal effect)

Tags: dnd-4e

Is there a way to create the *"Mehrune's Razor"* effect from *"The Elder Scrolls"* in 4e?

The original effect was something like this:  on hit a roll of a natural 20 the target instantly dies, there is no save.  Only a natural 20 roll triggers the effect, and no other power or effect increases the chances of an instant kill while using the blade.  If a natural 20 is not rolled, the weapon does damage like a weapon of it's type (e.g. dagger, sword, axe, etc)

I would have used the term `Vorpal`, but 4e now has a completely different effect for the `Vorpal` concept, which I think nerfs the vorpal blade into near uselessness.

Comment: Someone might also want to answer with the effect this would have on game balance and style ...

Answer (score 5):

You're pretty much limited to house rules and/or custom items for this. There are very, very few auto-kill abilities in 4e (in fact, Orcus' wand might be the only one).

On a side note, Vorpal can be good under the right conditions, such as on a glaive that's been given the brutal property by an artificer.

Comment: I'll check Orcus's wand again, I forgot it had that power.